# How to display characters in a write() funtion C

Tags: c

I'm trying to display a certain way of outputting information. Right now I'm using Vim in the shell of Linux

1. to display a 'char' written in a function
2. it has to be portrayed like this

```
void ft_putchar(char c);
```

AND it has to be displayed via another function like so

```
write(1, &c, 1);
```

Right now I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, but I have many error codes.

I tried putting both functions into the `main()` one but the only thing I receive while trying to compile are errors.
this is my code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void ft_putchar(char c);
{
        write(1, &c , 1)
}

int main(){
        ft_putchar('a');
}
```

and this is the error code -

> └─$ gcc ft_putchar.c
> ft_putchar.c:5:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token
> 5 | {
> | ^

Comment: Please post a [mre] and include the full error message as text in the question.

Comment: We don't know what you're doing wrong either if you don't present any code to us.

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding your English.  Are you trying to say that your goal is to *write a function* matching prototype `void ft_putchar(char c);`?  And that that function is or should be implemented as `write(1, &c, 1);`?

Comment: You have a spurious semicolon (`;`) before the function's body's opening brace (`{`).

Comment: In the code now presented, delete the semicolon (`;`) from the line `void ft_putchar(char c);`.  That is inappropriate when you are not just declaring the function but also defining it (*i.e.* providing its body.  And add a semicolon after the `write()` call -- this is (or needs to be) a *statement*, and statements in C must always be terminated by semicolons.

Comment: @ikegami and John Bollinger thank you both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, ensure you have included the necessary header for the write function. The write function is defined in unistd.h, so you need to include this header at the top of your file.

Here's a simple example of how you might define ft_putchar and use it in a main function:

```
#include <unistd.h>

// Function declaration
void ft_putchar(char c);

int main() {
    // Example usage of ft_putchar
    ft_putchar('H');
    ft_putchar('e');
    ft_putchar('l');
    ft_putchar('l');
    ft_putchar('o');
    ft_putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}

// Function definition
void ft_putchar(char c) {
    write(1, &c, 1);
}
```

In this example:
The ft_putchar function takes a single character c as its parameter.
It then calls write, with 1 as the first argument to specify the file descriptor for standard output (stdout), &c to pass the address of the character to write (since write expects a pointer), and 1 as the third argument to specify that
we want to write one byte (since a char in C is typically one byte).